# @Html.RenderPartial causing @Html.CheckBoxFor to uncheck values

Tags: view, razor, partial

I have a partial view that I'm currently rendering and everything loads up nicely.  I also have a @Html.Checkboxfor that iterates through a collection of items and enables a check for the controller when the value is 'True'.  My problem is that the @Html.RenderPartial() seems to be unchecking all the values once it loads.  I've checked the model and the values are there, if I remove @Html.RenderPartial() for my partial view then the @Html.CheckBoxFor() will display the checked values.

I'd like to ask the SO community if there is a fix for something like this as I've tried other solutions, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Organization Access</legend>
<table>
<tr>
@{Html.RenderPartial("_OrganizationAccess");}
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Alerts</legend>
<table>
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.AlertMembership.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.AlertMembership[i].AlertStatus)</td>
<td>@Html.LabelForModel(Model.AlertMembership[i].AlertName)</td>
<td>@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.AlertMembership[i].AlertId)</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the problem was partial view's when rendered using (@HtmlRenderPartial("view here")) will load not only the content, but also affect the other DOM objects/attributes on the view page.  I traced the problem down to an issue where the inputs where being checked to false.  This is why the @Html.CheckBoxFor was showing 'false" for the checked attribute after the partial view rendered.